# Media queries for html meta tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a mobile site. We have two pages that are mobile optimized. The rest of the pages are just supposed to be the desktop page that when loads fits the screen. The tricky part with this is that we have a dynamic jQuery menu bar at the top that as the window size shrinks in width, the menu bar shrinks to fit the page and eventually if the window is too small it collapses all the menu options into a a single menu button.

I've been told to change this so that this menu button only appears on the two pages that are mobile optimized and show the desktop page (without the menu button) for all the other pages. To do this I want want to use `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=.xx">` where I would change the values of xx based off of a CSS media query. The issue I'm having is that the `meta` tag is html and the media query is CSS. So I can't actually change the initial scale based of the media query. Is there a way around this?

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use jq to add a class to body when the size is small, and then you can prefix any css rules anywhere with ex: "body.small " to apply them only when the viewport is small.

Comment: why would you want to use `initial-scale` for that? just show and hide the menu with CSS Media queries. That's called Responsive Web Design. http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/